# Matlab : Help in modulus operation

Tags: matlab, modulus

I am trying to implement a map / function which has the equation [Bernoulli Shift Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_transformation)

x_n+1 = 2* x_n mod 1

The output of this map will be a binary number which will be either 0/1.

So, I generated the first sample x_1 using rand. The following is the code. The problem is I am getting real numbers. When using a digital calculator, I can get binary, whereas when using Matlab, I am getting real numbers. Please help where I am going wrong. Thank you.

```
>> x = rand();
>> x

x =

    0.1647

>> y = mod(2* x,1)

y =

    0.3295
```

Comment: use `x=randi([0 1])` to get integer between 0 and 1, and be aware that `mod(x,1)` will **always** return 0 (There is no remainder in a division by 1). You might want to use `y=mod(2*x,2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misunderstood your question because I focused on the assumption you had that the output should be binary [`0` or `1`], which is wrong.

To reproduce the output of the dyadic transformation as in the link you provided, your code works fine (for 1 value), and you can use this function to calculate `N` terms (assuming a starting term `x0`) :

```
function x = dyadic(x0,n)

x = zeros(n,1) ; %// preallocate output vector
x(1) = x0 ;      %// assign first term

for k=2:n
    x(k) = mod( 2*x(k-1) , 1) ; %// calculate all terms of the serie
end
```

Note that the output does not have to be *binary*, it has to be ***between*** `0` and `1`.

In the case of integers, the result of `mod(WhateverInteger,1)` is always `0`, but in the case of *Real* numbers (which is what you use here), the result of `mod(AnyRealNumber,1)` will be the fractional part, so a number between `0` and `1`. (`1` is mathematically excluded, `0` is possible by the `mod(x,1)` operation, but in the case of your serie it means all the successive term will be zero too).

Comment: The default behavior of round is MATLAB is exactly equal to the hard threshold equation used by the article.

Answer (score 2):

The dyadic transformation seems to be a transformation from [0,1) continuous to [0,1) continuous. I see nothing wrong with your test code if you are trying to implement the dyadic mapping. You should be expecting output in the [0,1)

Comment: Based on how I read equation. It seems the y in your original code is really x(k+1). Once you compute x(k+1). y = round(x(k+1)). That will satisfy equation 3.

Comment: You are right in saying that the variable y is x(k+1). In essence, the output of Eq(3) will be real numbers in the range [0,1). Will rounding off operation be equivalent to the thresholding using 0.5 in order to get binary numbers? Won't there be a difference in the values?

Comment: Furthermore, Hoki says that when i do x(k+1) = mod(2*x, 1) , the code will always return 0 as there is no remainder in a division by 1. Can you please clarify what is the actual code/equation to generate x(k+1) and then how to convert it to 0 and 1?

Comment: @SKM, forget what I said about modulo, this applied only for integers, but hiandbaii is right, in your case the results are _in the interval_ [0,1).